# Windows Services does not show up in Services snap-in

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have created a WCF service; its working fine in Visual studio. I have added a Project Installer in the same project which basically has an instance of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller and also an instance of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller. Then I also created setup project for it. The setup process seem to work fine; however this service just does not show up "services snap-in". Any ideas what i might be missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WCF service itself is **not** a Windows service that will show up in that snap-in!

You might choose to build a self-hosting Windows NT Service - but that's an additional step - so the Windows NT Service would be hosting the WCF service - so you have two services here in play. Only the Windows NT Service (which typically derives from [`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx)) will be installable as a Windows Service and show up in the service snap-in.

See: [MSDN How to: HOst a WCF Services in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) for more information and code samples.